# Linux timeout command using actual time? Broken binary?

Tags: arch-linux, timeout

I want to have `timeout` kill a script after one hour.

On debian I run `timeout 1h <script>` and it simply works.

On my arch linux machine, things are different. After trying some stuff I think I figured out that the issue is that my timeout binary doesn't use the actual system time, but the CPU time. The script I want to timeout uses `wget` which apparently doesn't use a lot of CPU time. A `timeout 3600 wget` command can run for up to half a day before being terminated.

`timeout 5 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` however gets killed after 6.6 seconds of clock time (5.1 seconds of CPU time).

I'm unable to find the `timeout` binary (clarification: **Not** on my system, I mean on the web for download), every source says "it comes with linux" basically. My `timeout` doesn't have a `--version` or `--help`, no matter what it just says this:

```
Usage:
    timeout [-t timelimit] [-m memlimit] [-x hertz] command [arguments ...]

Died at /usr/local/bin/timeout line 29
```

Do I somehow have a messed up binary? According to `man timeout`, both version and help options should be available. Since `timeout` is part of the linux core, how do I re-install?

Comment: Depending on your shell there are some commands to find out where a certain binary is located and whether it's e.g. a shell builtin.

In bash for example you could use `type timeout` or `which timeout` or `whereis timeout` to find out more about timeout's whereabouts.

Comment: I located a timeout binary in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`, both are identical and give the same results.

Comment: The usage output indicates you are not calling the GNU timeout binary. Is it actually a binary? What gives `file /usr/local/bin/timeout`?

Comment: @Lambert I suspected that at first and tried a `cat` on them. Gives a lot of `�`, makes me think it's binary. `file` gives: `/usr/bin/timeout: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: Oh. Then you have two timeout binaries. The "died" error from your initial post mentions `/usr/local/bin/timeout`, whereas your last follow-up mentions `/usr/bin/timeout`. What if we moved `/usr/local/bin/timeout` in /root (or anywhere your PATH won't look at for binaries), and try running your script again?

Comment: @SYN This is weird but you seem to be correct. I could've sworn I ran both binaries with their absolute path before with same results. I just checked sha256 sums and the results differed. I removed `/usr/local/bin`'s timeout and voila - `timeout --help` does now work, and the `timeout` command works as expected. Do you mind leaving a full answer so I can accept it? Only thing I don't really understand is how that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading back on initial post and its comments, it sounds like the issue would be related to two different copies of the timeout binary being present. One in `/usr/local/bin`, the other in `/usr/bin`.

Moving one or the other out, somewhere your shell won't look for binaries, should help figuring out which is which. Assuming `/usr/bin` is more likely to be used for system binaries, the one in `/usr/local/bin` is probably our problem - though I could be wrong.

You may query your package manager, on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/timeout
coreutils: /usr/bin/timeout
```

Or CentOS, RedHat, Fedora, ... :

```
$ yum provides /usr/bin/timeout
...
coreutils-8.22-24.el7.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/timeout
```

Whereas there's a fair chance your package manager doesn't know a thing about `/usr/local/bin/timeout`.